# How to change timezone in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to change timezone of ruby. My machine is now in Indian timezone. when I am doing `Time.now` then it's giving me time in India time zone. I want to change the timezone of ruby to 'central time US & Canada' without changing my machine timezone.

Please let me know how to change timezone in ruby without changing machine timezone.

Comment: Pure Ruby or Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Have you seen this gem? https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone